# replace Specific text to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to replace or change specific text to new html?

Old HTML:

```
<div id="test">    
    <p>
        [b] lorem ipsum [/b]
    </p>
    <p>
        [textarea] lorem ipsum [/textarea] 
    </p>
</div>
```

New HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <p>
        <b>lorem ipsum</b>
    </p>
    <p>
        <textarea>lorem ipsum</textarea>
    </p>
</div>
```

```js
Force_Tag = [
    '[b]','<pre>',
    '[/b]','</b>',
    '[textarea]','<textarea>',
    '[/textarea]','</textarea>',
    // ...
]
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code so it's readable. I've fixed it for you in this question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: thanks for edit my question... i am newbie on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\[)|(\])/g` to capture `"["`, `"]"`, replace first capture group with `"<"`, second capture group with `">"`, set `.innerHTML` of elements to replacement strings

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>
    [b] lorem ipsum [/b]
  </p>
  <p>
    [textarea] lorem ipsum [/textarea]
  </p>
</div>
<script>
  for (let p of document.querySelectorAll("#test p")) {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/(\[)|(\])/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
      if (p1) return "<";
      if (p2) return ">"
    })
  }
  </script>
```